# How to grep only sentence which contains may one or more space between two word

Tags: linux, shell

I want to grep only sentence which contains may one or more space between two word.

Example

```
1. always  @    ( posedge clk  or     posedge rst )      //Test
2. always @ ( posedge clock )begin //or negedge reset) begin
3. always  @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)      //Test
4. always @ ( posedge clock ) //or negedge reset) begin
```

Here I want to grep only serial number 1 and 3. Output should be:

```
1. always  @    ( posedge clk  or     posedge rst )      //Test
3. always  @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)      //Test
```

How can I grep?

Comment: Which "two words" are you looking for there?

Answer (score 0):

With this as the input file (copied and pasted from the question source):

```
$ cat >file
1. always  @    ( posedge clk  or     posedge rst )      //Test
2. always @ ( posedge clock )begin //or negedge reset) begin
3. always  @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)      //Test
4. always @ ( posedge clock ) //or negedge reset) begin
```

As best I can tell, you are looking for all lines with two or more consecutive spaces anywhere in the line.  In that case:

```
$ grep '  ' file
1. always  @    ( posedge clk  or     posedge rst )      //Test
3. always  @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)      //Test
```